# Erro 500 Tomcat: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2.2, tomcat, primefaces-3.5

**Web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>ProjWebFinal</display-name>  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>Login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>    
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

**Login.xhtml**

```hmtl
<<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

  <h:head>
     <title>Login</title>
  </h:head>

  <h:body>
     <h:outputText value="#{LoginBean.nome}"></h:outputText><br/>
     <h:outputText value="#{LoginBean.senha}"></h:outputText><br/>

  </h:body>

</html>
```

**Login.java**

```java
package controle;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name = "LoginBean") 

public class Login {

    private String nome;
    private String senha;   

    public Login(String nome,String senha){

        this.setNome(nome);
        this.setSenha(senha);
    }

    public void setNome(String nome){

        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome(){

        return this.nome;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha){

        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public String getSenha(){

        return this.senha;
    }
}
```

Esta dando o erro 500 ao tentar rodar o Login.xhtml, o erro abaixo:

> ```
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>   at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getAttributes(Unknown Source)
>   at org.primefaces.context.RequestContext.setCurrentInstance(RequestContext.java:70)
>   at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.<init>(PrimeFacesContext.java:33)
>   at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContextFactory.getFacesContext(PrimeFacesContextFactory.java:34)
>   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> ```

Comment: Com o   `<h:body></h:body>` vazio (removendo os `h:outputText`) o erro ainda ocorre?

Comment: Qual a versão do JSF que esta utilizando?

Comment: No seu bean, não há um escopo definido, ou você o configurou via xml, faces-config.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Veja essa parte do código:

```
<<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Tem uma "<" sobrando. Veja se é isso

Comment: Tirei a "<" mais não funcionou